# JavaScript if statement inside EventListener is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

if statement not working properly, always showing result of the else statement .
i want to be alerted correct when the second box is clicked but it always alert wrong aka the else statement.
i am new in these things and getting hard time figuring it out.

```js
var colors = [
"rgb(255,0,0)",
"rgb(255,255,0)"];

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var pickedColor = colors[1];

for(var i=0;i<squares.length;i++)
{
 squares[i].style.background=colors[i];

 squares[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
  var clickedColor = this.style.background;
  if(clickedColor === pickedColor){
   alert("correct");
  }
  else{
   alert("wrong");
  }
 });
}
```

```css
.square{
 width: 10%;

 padding-bottom: 10%;
 float: left;
 margin: 1.66%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>color game</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="square"></div>
 <div class="square"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint to debug your variable assignment?

Comment: If I were you, I would console.log `clickedColor` and `pickedColor` inside the event listener and see if they match, you might find some subtle difference you are not expecting

Comment: thanks for helping. really grateful.

Comment: Were you able to get the answer?

Comment: yes with u guys help i get the answer. again thanks

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer correct, if it was of help.

Comment: yes i will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see the `clickedColor` and `pickedColor` is not the same, it's having spaces in between.

So to **remove spaces**, add the below code.

```
var clickedColor = this.style.backgroundColor.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

---

```js
var colors = [
"rgb(255,0,0)",
"rgb(255,255,0)"];

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var pickedColor = colors[1];

for(var i=0;i<squares.length;i++)
{
 squares[i].style.background=colors[i];

 squares[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
  var clickedColor = this.style.backgroundColor.replace(/\s/g, '');
    console.log([clickedColor.replace(/\s/g, ''),pickedColor]);
  if(clickedColor == pickedColor){
   alert("correct");
  }
  else{
   alert("wrong");
  }
 });
}
```

```css
.square{
 width: 10%;

 padding-bottom: 10%;
 float: left;
 margin: 1.66%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>color game</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="square"></div>
 <div class="square"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `this.style.background` return background color with spaces inside, not the same strings:

```
 colors[1] => "rgb(255,255,0)"

 this.style.background => "rgb(255, 255, 0)"
                                   ^^   ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that the string you try to compare does not match.

"rgb(255,255,0)" vs "rgb(255, 255, 0)".

You can either change your strings in your array:

```
 var colors = [
    "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
    "rgb(255, 255, 0)"
];
```

or (better imo): remove the spaces from what you retreive:

```
var clickedColor = this.style.background.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

See the below snippet to show the difference in strings:

```js
var colors = [
"rgb(255,0,0)",
"rgb(255,255,0)"];

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var pickedColor = colors[1];

for(var i=0;i<squares.length;i++)
{
 squares[i].style.background=colors[i];
 squares[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
  var clickedColor = this.style.background;
        console.log(pickedColor);
        console.log(clickedColor);
  if(clickedColor === pickedColor){
   alert("correct");
  }
  else{
   alert("wrong");
  }
 });
}
```

```css
.square{
 width: 10%;

 padding-bottom: 10%;
 float: left;
 margin: 1.66%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>color game</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="square"></div>
 <div class="square"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to add to the previous comments that simple removal of the white space might not be sufficient for all browsers. Firefox for instance puts slightly longer rule for the background that looks something like this:
`rgb(255, 255, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0%`

You should account for that too when implementing your solution. Maybe reading the value from `this.style.backgroundColor` is a good idea.